# Prove that $\sum\limits_{k}\sum\limits_{i\le k}\binom{n}{i}\cdot\sum\limits_{j>k}\binom{n}{j}=\frac{n}{2}\binom{2n}{n}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

**Question:**

> show  that
>
> $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\cdots+\binom{n}{k}\right)\left(\binom{n}{k+1}+\cdots+\binom{n}{n}\right)=\dfrac{n}{2}\binom{2n}{n}$$

My idea: let $$a_{k}=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\cdots+\binom{n}{k},b_{k}=\binom{n}{k+1}+\cdots+\binom{n}{n}$$

so use Abel identity
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{k}b_{k}=S_{n-1}b_{n-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}S_{k}[b_{k}-b_{k+1}]$$
where $$S_{n}=a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}$$

then I can't  continue,becase I can't how to deal the $S_{k}[b_{k}-b_{k+1}]$

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 8):

$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{n}{i}\right)\left(\sum_{j=k+1}^n\binom{n}{j}\right)\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^k\sum_{j=k+1}^n\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{\substack{i,j=0\\i\lt j}}^n\sum_{k=i}^{j-1}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{\substack{i,j=0\\i\lt j}}^n(j-i)\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}\tag{4}\\
&=n\sum_{\substack{i,j=0\\i\lt j}}^n\left[\binom{n}{i}\binom{n-1}{j-1}-\binom{n-1}{i-1}\binom{n}{j}\right]\tag{5}\\
&=n\sum_{\substack{i,j=0\\i\lt j}}^n\left[\binom{n-1}{i}\binom{n-1}{j-1}-\binom{n-1}{i-1}\binom{n-1}{j}\right]\tag{6}\\
&=n\sum_{\substack{i,j=0\\i\lt j}}^n\left[\binom{n-1}{i+1}\binom{n-1}{j}-\binom{n-1}{i-1}\binom{n-1}{j}\right]\tag{7}\\
&=n\sum_{j=0}^n\left[\binom{n-1}{j}\binom{n-1}{j}+\binom{n-1}{j-1}\binom{n-1}{j}\right]\tag{8}\\[6pt]
&=n\left[\binom{2n-2}{n-1}+\binom{2n-2}{n-2}\right]\tag{9}\\[6pt]
&=n\binom{2n-1}{n-1}\tag{10}\\[6pt]
&=\frac n2\binom{2n}{n}\tag{11}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\:\ (2)$: distribute product over sum
$\:\ (3)$: change order of summation
$\:\ (4)$: evaluate sum in $k$
$\:\ (5)$: $k\binom{n\vphantom{1}}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$
$\:\ (6)$: $\binom{n\vphantom{1}}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k}+\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ (Pascal recursion)
$\:\ (7)$: reindex the sum of the left term
$\:\ (8)$: telescoping sum
$\:\ (9)$: sum each term using [Vandermonde's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)
$(10)$: $\binom{n\vphantom{1}}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k}+\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ (Pascal recursion)
$(11)$: $n\binom{2n}{n}=2n\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$ ( similar to $(5)$ )

Answer (score 6):

> A general principle in such contexts is to try *to get rid of the limits of the sums* and that, to do so, *indicator functions* are exquisitely tailored.

In the present case, using the convention that ${k\choose i}=0$ for *every integers* $(k,i)$ except when $k$ and $i$ are two nonnegative integers such that $k\geqslant i$ (and then ${k\choose i}$ is the usual binomial coefficient, of course), one sees that the LHS of the question is $$S_n=\sum_k\sum_{i\leqslant k}{n\choose i}\sum_{j\gt k}{n\choose j}=\sum_{k,i,j}{n\choose i}{n\choose j}\mathbf 1_{i\leqslant k\lt j}.$$
The RHS above is a triple sum *without delimiters* (a sum on $\mathbb Z^3$, if you like) hence we can start to work on it.

For each $i\lt j$ there are $j-i$ integers $k$ such that $i\leqslant k\lt j$ hence $$S_n=\sum_{i,j}(j-i){n\choose i}{n\choose j}\mathbf 1_{i\lt j}=U_n-V_n,$$ with $$U_n=\sum_{i,j}j{n\choose i}{n\choose j}\mathbf 1_{i\lt j},\qquad V_n=\sum_{i,j}i{n\choose i}{n\choose j}\mathbf 1_{i\lt j}.$$
Using the identity $j{n\choose j}=n{n-1\choose j-1}$ and the change of variable $j\to j-1$ in the first sum and the identity $i{n\choose j}=n{n-1\choose i-1}$ and the change of variable $i\to i-1$ in the second sum, one gets $$U_n=n\sum_{i,j}{n\choose i}{n-1\choose j}\mathbf 1_{i\leqslant j},\qquad V_n=n\sum_{i,j}{n-1\choose i}{n\choose j}\mathbf 1_{i\lt j-1}.$$ The change of variables $k=n-1-i$, $\ell=n-j$ in $V_n$ transforms the condition $i\lt j-1$ into $\ell\lt k$ hence $$ V_n=n\sum_{k,\ell}{n-1\choose n-1-k}{n\choose n-\ell}\mathbf 1_{\ell\lt k}=n\sum_{k,\ell}{n\choose \ell}{n-1\choose k}\mathbf 1_{\ell\lt k}.$$
Renaming $(\ell,k)$ as $(i,j)$ and comparing the RHS with $U_n$, one sees that all the terms in $U_n-V_n$ cancel except those such that $i=j$, thus, $$S_n=n\sum_{i}{n\choose i}{n-1\choose i}=n\sum_{i}{n\choose i}{n-1\choose n-1-i}.$$ The sum in the RHS is the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ in the polynomial $$(1+x)^n\cdot(1+x)^{n-1}=(1+x)^{2n-1},$$ hence, finally, $$S_n=n\cdot{2n-1\choose n-1}=\frac12n\cdot{2n\choose n}.$$

Comment: (+1) Looking closely at your answer, I think everything in my answer is pretty much the same. I am still looking to see how you bypassed step $(6)$ in my answer.

Comment: Ah, I see. you used $\binom{n\vphantom{1}}{i}\binom{n-1}{j-1}-\binom{n-1}{i-1}\binom{n\vphantom{1}}{j}=\binom{n\vphantom{1}}{n-i}\binom{n-1}{n-j}-\binom{n-1}{i-1}\binom{n\vphantom{1}}{j}$ and remapped indices. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we seek to show that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}
\left(\sum_{q=0}^k {n\choose q}\right)
\left(\sum_{q=k+1}^n {n\choose q}\right)
= \frac{1}{2} n {2n\choose n}.$$

Using the integral representation
$${n\choose q} = {n\choose n-q}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{n-q+1}} \; dz$$

we get for the first factor
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{n+1}}
\sum_{q=0}^k z^q \; dz
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{n+1}}
\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-z} \; dz
\\ = 2^n - \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{n+1}}
\frac{z^{k+1}}{1-z} \; dz$$

and for the second factor
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{n+1}}
\frac{z^{k+1}-z^{n+1}}{1-z} \; dz
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{n+1}}
\frac{z^{k+1}}{1-z} \; dz.$$

These add to $2^n$ as they obviously should.

Summing  from  $k=0$  to  $n-1$  we  get a  positive  and  a  negative
piece. The positive piece is

$$2^n \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{n}}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{z^{k}}{1-z} \; dz
\\ = 2^n \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{n}}
\frac{1-z^n}{(1-z)^2} \; dz
\\ = 2^n \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{n}}
\frac{1}{(1-z)^2} \; dz.$$

The negative piece is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z_1|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z_1)^n}{z_1^{n}(1-z_1)}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z_2|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z_2)^n}{z_2^{n}(1-z_2)}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} z_1^k z_2^k
\; dz_2 \; dz_1
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z_1|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z_1)^n}{z_1^{n}(1-z_1)}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z_2|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z_2)^n}{z_2^{n}(1-z_2)}
\frac{1-z_1^n z_2^n}{1-z_1z_2}
\; dz_2 \; dz_1
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z_1|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z_1)^n}{z_1^{n}(1-z_1)}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z_2|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z_2)^n}{z_2^{n}(1-z_2)}
\frac{1}{1-z_1z_2}
\; dz_2 \; dz_1.$$

We evaluate the  inner integral by taking the sum  of the negatives of
the  residues of  the  poles  at $z_2=1$  and  $z_2=1/z_1$ instead  of
computing the residue  of the pole at zero by using  the fact that the
residues sum to zero.

Re-write the integral as follows.
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z_2|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z_2)^n}{z_2^{n}(z_2-1)}
\frac{1}{z_1z_2-1}
\; dz_2
\\ = \frac{1}{z_1} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z_2|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z_2)^n}{z_2^{n}(z_2-1)}
\frac{1}{z_2-1/z_1}
\; dz_2.$$

Now the negative of the residue at $z_2 = 1$ is 
$$-\frac{1}{z_1} 2^n \frac{1}{1-1/z_1} = 2^n \frac{1}{1-z_1}.$$

Substituting this into the outer integral we get
$$2^n\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z_1|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z_1)^n}{z_1^{n}(1-z_1)^2} \; dz_1.$$

We see that this piece precisely cancels the positive piece that we
obtained first.

Continuing the negative of the residue at $z_2 = 1/z_1$ is
$$-\frac{1}{z_1} \frac{(1+1/z_1)^n}{1/z_1^n \times (1/z_1-1)}
= -\frac{1}{z_1} \frac{(1+z_1)^n}{(1/z_1-1)}
= - \frac{(1+z_1)^n}{(1-z_1)}.$$

We  now substitute  this into  the  outer integral  flipping the  sign
because this was the negative piece to get
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z_1|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z_1)^{2n}}{z_1^{n}(1-z_1)^2} \; dz_1.$$

Extracting the residue at $z_1=0$ we get
$$\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {2n\choose n-1-q} (q+1)
= \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {2n\choose n+q+1} (q+1)
\\ = - n \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {2n\choose n+q+1}
+ \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {2n\choose n+q+1} (n+q+1)
\\ = -n \left(\frac{1}{2} 2^{2n} - \frac{1}{2} {2n\choose n}\right)
+ 2n \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {2n-1\choose n+q}
\\ = -n \left(\frac{1}{2} 2^{2n} - \frac{1}{2} {2n\choose n}\right)
+ 2n \frac{1}{2} 2^{2n-1}
\\ = \frac{1}{2} n {2n\choose n}.$$

**Remark.** If we want to do this properly we also need to verify that
the residue  at infinity of  the inner integral  is zero.  We  use the
formula for the residue at infinity

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=\infty} h(z)
= \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} 
\left[-\frac{1}{z^2} h\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right]$$

which in the present case gives for the inner term in $z_2$
$$- \mathrm{Res}_{z_2=0} \frac{1}{z_2^2} 
\frac{(1+1/z_2)^n}{1/z_2^n \times (1-1/z_2)} \frac{1}{1-z_1/z_2}
\\ = - \mathrm{Res}_{z_2=0} \frac{1}{z_2^2} 
\frac{(1+z_2)^n}{(1-1/z_2)} \frac{1}{1-z_1/z_2}
\\ = - \mathrm{Res}_{z_2=0}
\frac{(1+z_2)^n}{(z_2-1)} \frac{1}{z_2-z_1}$$
which is zero by inspection.